# How do I put $\sqrt{x+1}$ into exponential notation?

Tags: calculus

I think $\sqrt{x+1} = x^{1/2} + 1^{1/2}$. Is this incorrect? Why or why not?

Comment: Take x=1, $sqrt(2)=2$..

Comment: Only in characteristic $1/2$ ...

Comment: $(x+1)^2=(x+1)(x+1)=x^2+2x+1^2$...not $x^2+1^2$...you can't assume that $(x+1)^{1/2}=x^{1/2}+1^{1/2}$.

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect, because $\sqrt{x+1}\neq\sqrt x+\sqrt1$

Comment: How do we put this in exponential notation; isn't it simply given by: $\exp(1/2\cdot \log(x+1))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember the formula for fractional exponents:
$$x^\frac{m}{n} = \sqrt[n]{x^m}$$
It can also be written as:
$$x^\frac{m}{n} = (\sqrt[n]{x})^m$$
$\sqrt{x+1}$ can be rewritten as $\sqrt[2]{(x+1)^1}$
Using our formula, we can say that:
$$\sqrt[2]{(x+1)^1} = (x+1)^\frac{1}{2}$$
Also remember that:
$$x^m + y^m \neq (x+y)^m$$
You should be familiar with the Pythagorean triple $3-4-5$. It can be easily seen that:
$$3^2 + 4^2 \neq (3+4)^2 \neq 7^2$$
$$3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$$
I will now go back to the original question. You think that:
$$\sqrt{x+1} = x^\frac{1}{2} + 1^\frac{1}{2}$$
Let us expand $x^\frac{1}{2} + 1^\frac{1}{2}$.
$$x^\frac{1}{2} + 1^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=\sqrt[2]{x^1} + \sqrt[2]{1^1}$$
$$=\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1}$$
$$=\sqrt{x} + 1$$
$$\sqrt{x} + 1 \neq \sqrt{x+1}$$
So, because $\sqrt{x} + 1 \neq \sqrt{x+1}$, then $\sqrt{x+1} \neq x^\frac{1}{2} + 1^\frac{1}{2}$. The correct answer is:
$$\sqrt{x+1} = (x+1)^\frac{1}{2}$$
Before I forget, always remember the restrictions on $\sqrt{x+1} = (x+1)^\frac{1}{2}$. If $x < -1$. then the statement is false, because you cannot have negative square roots. TECHNICALLY, it is not false because *complex numbers* cover negative square roots. But for the purposes of this question, *UNLESS* you have learned about complex numbers and the number $i$, the statement is false if $x < -1$.
**RESTRICTIONS ON $\sqrt{x+1} = (x+1)^\frac{1}{2}$:**
$x ≥ 1$
$\sqrt{x+1} ≥ 0$
$(x+1)^\frac{1}{2} ≥ 0$
I hope I have enlightened you a bit :)

---

**EDIT:** I do not want you to think that the statement $\sqrt{x}+1=\sqrt{x+1}$ is entirely false. There is a value of $x$ that will make the equation true. Let's find it.
$$\sqrt{x}+1=\sqrt{x+1}$$
$$x+2\sqrt{x}+1=x+1$$
$$2\sqrt{x}=0$$
$$4x=0$$
$$x=0$$
Checking for extraneous roots...
$$\sqrt{0}+1=\sqrt{0+1}$$
$$1=\sqrt{1}$$
$$1=1$$
So, $\sqrt{x}+1=\sqrt{x+1}$ when $x=0$.

Comment: Wow, best answer I have seen on here in a while. I understand it completely now, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not correct. $$\sqrt{x+1} = (x+1)^{1/2}\neq x^{1/2} + 1^{1/2}$$

Equality holds only if $x = 0$.

Generally speaking, $(x + y)^p \neq x^p + y^p$, where $p$ is some power. Equality holds if and only if $x=0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: Should be $(x+y)^p \neq x^p+y^p, \\ p\neq 1$

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle\sqrt a+\sqrt b=\sqrt{a+b}$

Squaring either sides 
$\displaystyle\implies (\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2=a+b\iff 2\sqrt{ab}=0\iff ab=0$

$\implies$ at least one of $a,b$ is zero

So, here $x$ has to be zero

Answer (score 1):

$$
9^{1/2} + 16^{1/2} = 3 + 4 = 7 \ne 5 = 25^{1/2} = (9+16)^{1/2}.
$$

So
$$
\left(\frac{9}{16}\right)^{1/2} + 1^{1/2} = \frac 3 4 + 1 = \frac 7 4 \ne \frac 5 4 = \left(\frac{25}{16}\right)^{1/2} = \left(\frac{9}{16}+1\right)^{1/2}
$$

In other words, if $x=\dfrac{9}{16}$ then $x^{1/2}+1^{1/2}$ is not at all the same as $(x+1)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Someone is trying to delete the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degen's_eight-square_identity *simply because he finds it uninteresting*. When laymen blunder into mathematical territory...

Comment: The deletion has now been withdrawn by a moderator.